# Unable to uninstall MSI created with MsiEmbeddedChainer table

Tags: windows-installer

I have created a simple MSI containing entries in the MsiEmbeddedChainer table

I have two entries:

1. Condition=NOT Installed
2. Condition=REMOVE

When I install the msi, my chained executable is called passing a transaction handle on the command line as expected and I am successfully able to install an embedded MSI using it.

If I run the msi again it does nothing as expected.

If I try to uninstall the msi, the uninstall says it is successful but my chained exe is not called, the msi remains in Add/Remove programs and no files are removed.

If I remove the MsiEmbeddedChainer table the msi installs and uninstalls as expected.

How should uninstalls work with embedded MSIs?

Comment: How are you invoking the uninstall in question, and on what OS? Two notes; the condition REMOVE can be true for examples that don't fully remove a product, and embedded chainers are less dependable than external chainers. I would strongly suggest using a bootstrap-based one if you have the option.

Comment: I am just testing using an admin command prompt at present on Windows 7. I realise REMOVE is not the best option to use due to upgrades etc but was just trying to get something to happen on uninstall. Unfortunately the whole point of the exercise is to create an MSI due to InTune limitations so using a bootstrapper is not an option

Comment: Okay, just ruling out some odd interactions with the new Windows 10 control panel. More details are probably required; have you looked at verbose logs or watched for exe launches with procmon? (Aside: I don't remember if embedded chainers even run as part of a major upgrade uninstall, so that bit might not matter.)

Comment: I am testing on Windows 7.
When I compare install logs with and without the chainer the only real difference is these 2 lines:
MSI (s) (3C:4C) [10:57:01:688]: Embedded Chainer - Searching for a valid Embedded Chainer to run
MSI (s) (3C:4C) [10:57:01:688]: Embedded Chainer - Scheduled to run after install
When I compare uninstall logs the only real difference are these lines:

Comment: MSI (s) (3C:C8) [11:02:54:932]: Embedded Chainer - Searching for a valid Embedded Chainer to run
MSI (s) (3C:C8) [11:02:54:932]: Embedded Chainer - Skipping chainer: Chainer (condition is false)
MSI (s) (3C:C8) [11:02:54:932]: Embedded Chainer - Scheduled to run after install

Comment: then a whole load of RegAddValue entries in the Install part of the registry which I find very confusing